# Facebook Send Button URI-error

Tags: facebook, button, send, xfbml

Set this code on my page:

```
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js?#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In Opera(last version) and IE(7,8,9) js errors appear:

IE - `URI-error: http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js?#xfbml=1`

Opera -

```
   Event thread: message
    Uncaught exception: URIError: Malformed URI
    Error thrown at line 5, column 622 in <anonymous function: decode>(f) in http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js?:
        d[a(c[0])]=a(c[1]||'');
    called from line 12, column 4409 in <anonymous function: recv>(b) in http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js?:
        b=FB.QS.decode(b);
    called from line 12, column 5266 in <anonymous function: onMessage>(event) in http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js?:
        FB.XD.recv(event.data);
```

Can help ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a facebook bug
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/156272457812857

Answer (score 0):

Try removing '?#xfbml=1' from the end:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/